# FreeCodeCamp: Iterating Through All an Array's Items Using For Loops

Tags: javascript

I've got this working block of code from the freecodecamp hint

```
  function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [...arr];

  for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++) {
      if(newArr[i][j] == elem) {
        newArr.splice(i,1);
        i--;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return newArr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

I understand most part of it but not 
`i--;
break;`
I really need an explanation as to why `i--; break;` was used.

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures/iterate-through-all-an-arrays-items-using-for-loops/

Comment: Because you're eliminating an element from the array. Because he's editing an array that's currently being looped through (Removing the current element), he needs to reverse the current index, so that it reads the NEXT element. Example A, B, C => Index 0: A, Index 1: B (He's removing), so now array is A C. If he doesn't reverse the index, the next loop would be Index 2: (0 is A, 1 is C, and 2 doesn't exist)

Comment: Thanks. I kinda get it a lil bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common question when a developer says, this code is skipping indexes.

You are altering the original array and removing the index. So think about it like a stack of blocks. You remove one, all of the ones above it drop down one.

So you are removing an item with splice, so you need to reduce the index by one so you do not skip over the item that fills in the gap.

```
A [B] C D E <-- before 
   ^
A [C] D E   <-- after
```

This is why people normally loop from the end to the start to avoid this.

Comment: I get it now but does `break` just make `i--` count once?

Comment: And how do you mean loop from the end?

Comment: break stops the inner loop `j` and goes to the outside loop `i`